# std::bad_alloc when concatenating two vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am having some issues when I concatenate 2 vectors.

```
std::vector<Transform3D> out;
for(double theta = 0; theta <= 2*M_PI ; theta+=1 )
{
    for(double phi = 0; phi <= M_PI ; phi+=1 )
    {
        double sphere_x = obj_x + r*cos(theta)*sin(phi);
        double sphere_y = obj_y + r*sin(theta)*sin(phi);
        double sphere_z = obj_z + + r*cos(phi);
        Transform3D<> transformation_matrix = transform(obj_x,obj_y,obj_z,sphere_x,sphere_y,sphere_z);

        if(0.01<(transformation_matrix.P()[0] - current_x) ||
            0.01<transformation_matrix.P()[1] - current_y ||
            0.01<transformation_matrix.P()[2] - current_z)
        {
            cout << "Interpolate: " << endl;
            std::vector<Transform3D> transformation_i = invKin_LargeDisplacement(transformation_matrix);

            out.insert(out.end(),transformation_i.begin(),transformation_i.end());
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "OK" << endl;
            out.push_back(transformation_matrix);
        }
        cout << out.size() << endl;
        cout << sizeof(Transform3D<>) << endl;
    }
}
```

`out.insert(..)` seems to cause the `bad_alloc`, but the extra data is needed.

While debugging the issue, I printed the size of the vector while running the for loop and got the following output:

```
Interpolate: 
6346700
Interpolate: 
12052200
Interpolate: 
16476100
Interpolate: 
20127501
Interpolate: 
26474201
Interpolate: 
32239601
Interpolate: 
36748301
Interpolate: 
40416502
Interpolate: 
46763202
Interpolate: 
52659402
Interpolate: 
57349102
Interpolate: 
61053903
Interpolate: 
67400603
Interpolate: 
73377503
Interpolate: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there some way I can avoid getting the `bad_alloc`, while still being able to interpolate?

Comment: You run out of memory. Time to look where you can trim memory usage.

Comment: I haven't used the swap yet..

Comment: 73 million objects can be a lot of memory.  What is `sizeof(rw::math::Transform3D<>)`?

Comment: The swap doesn't increase your virtual memory space.

Comment: Also, a vector implementation is allowed to reserve some capacity when you push_back. And a common heuristic is to double the capacity the vector auto-reserves each time, to decrease allocation overhead. You could try calling `reserve` yourself with a constant increase and see if it helps.

Comment: okay so 73 million times 97 = 6.5 GB of memory.

Comment: But i have 16 gb of ram?

Comment: You actual RAM doesn't matter as much as the virtual space of the process. Also, is it a 32 or 64 bit executable?

Comment: There is not enough information here. But you are running out of memory.

Comment: @Lamda Don't forget though that you need to have 2 blocks of memory allocated in order to copy if the vector gets resized which or then likely does happen.  You have the old block from the vector and the new block it is copying everything into.  That there is about 13 GB of ram plus you have the temporary vector and anything else running on the system.

Comment: hmm... Well. 
There seems to be no way around than constraining my problem into a manageable size.. 
Mystery solved :)

Comment: @Lamda You could sacrifice speed for storage and use a linked list.  The you will not have re-sizing issues and you can soak up all of the ram as a vector needs a contiguous block where a list can fit elements in memory.  I would profile it to see if the decrease in speed is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume your transform is a PoD with a 4x4 array of floats (4 bytes):

size of transform = 4*4*4 = 64 bytes
size of array at exception = 73377503

64 * 73377503 = 4696160192 Bytes = 4.696160192 Gigabytes

With a vector of this magnitude I expect you ran out of memory...

How much memory do you have in your machine and do you really need 4.7Gb of transform data?

If so perhaps consider either compressing the data in memory and/or writing it to a file cache.